# Book recommendation for complex numbers and co-ordinate geometry

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, soft-question, book-recommendation

Can someone suggest me good book for **complex numbers** and **co-ordinate geometry** with good tough questions I have not explored these subjects much so I wanted to further become fluent in these segments of mathematics.

Comment: are you preparing for JEE? Or Olympiads?

Comment: JEE and solved Arihant and cengage but I don't feel satisfied in these two chapters

Comment: Well if you've done both, then, I would recommend FIITJEE's Review Package for JEE(Advanced) for questions only. This contains previous years AITS questions. So, this will be a great practice book.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *Complex Numbers & Geometry*, by Liang-shin Hahn.